# Switching Sound to Different Monitor

Tags: nvidia, sound, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.  I have an LCD monitor that has built-in speakers which I use as my default monitor.  I also have an LCD TV which I use as a second monitor sometimes to watch shows from the couch.

Both are hooked up to my graphics card via HDMI cables.  I can get the displays to go into Twinview via NVidia X Server Settings, but I can't figure out how to get the audio to switch from the monitor speakers to the TV speakers.

There is no audio section in the NVidia settings, and the sound section in System Settings can only see my default monitor apparently.

Comment: Does your nvidia card have multiple HDMI ports, or is one hooked up through a DVI converter? I've yet to see a card with multiple native HDMI ports. Have you tried swapping the cables?

Comment: Another place to look is in the pulseaudio settings for the system. See if there's multiple HDMI audio output entries for you to select.

Comment: There are 2 DVI ports on my graphics card.  I've got a DVI-to-HDMI converter on each.  I just tried switching the cables, and indeed, the sound switched over to the TV.  It is a fix, but I'd like to be able to switch the sound back and forth from the desktop instead of crawling under my desk to switch cables every time I want to watch something on the TV.  I also looked at pulseaudio settings, and the same devices are shown there as the regular settings menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind.  I've figured out a way to do it.  If I switch to Twinview, then disable my default monitor, the TV becomes the only monitor, and thus the default, and the sound automatically switches to it.